# Is it possible to include HTML snippets (partials) using gulp and Handlebars?

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js

What I need is same functionality as php's include(), but using gulp and handlebars. I have seen that this is possible using gulp and nunjucks, but am wondering if Handlebars can do it as well, as I prefer Handlebar's syntax to that of Nunjuck's.